# Unable to switch between frames in WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on contacts creation page in www.salesforce.com developer login account. Anybody can create a free developer login account and access this page.

I am unable to switch between frames in Lookup window. There are two frames, one is search frame with textbox and button to search and below that is results frame for displaying search results with hyperlinks for selection. I am specifying the frames by frame name or id, but webDriver switches to search frame and does the searching but then is not able to locate the results frame with NoSuchFrameException.

If I do not switch to search frame initially but directly switch to results frame, it is indeed successful in the locating the results frame which displays results of some recent searches done by default.

How do I switch from search frame to results frame ? Given below is my code

```
 public class Acc_Parent 
 {
  WebDriver driver;
  FileInputStream fis;
  XSSFWorkbook wb;
  XSSFSheet sh;

  @Test
  public void createParent() throws IOException, InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException 
  {
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
   //driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  driver.get("https://test.salesforce.com");
  fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/psit/Documents/Login.xlsx");
  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Login']")).click();

  fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/psit/Documents/Input.xlsx");
  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  sh = wb.getSheet("Parent");

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Account_Tab']/a")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hotlist']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_id0:acctFrm:nmsrch']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_id0:acctFrm']/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")).click();
  try
  {
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("click here")).click();

      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='parentAcc']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='childAcc']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
      Thread.sleep(2000);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:0:actFields']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:2:actFields']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:4:actFields']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:6:actFields']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(6).getStringCellValue());
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:8:actFields']")).sendKeys(Integer.toString((int)sh.getRow(1).getCell(7).getNumericCellValue()));
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:1:actFields']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(8).getStringCellValue());
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:3:actFields']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(9).getStringCellValue());

      String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:5:actFields_lkwgt']/img")).click();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      Set<String> winhand = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for(String str : winhand)
        {   
            if(!str.equalsIgnoreCase(mainWindow))
            {
                driver.switchTo().window(str);
                break;
            }
        }
        try
        {

            driver.switchTo().frame("searchFrame");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lksrch']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(10).getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='theForm']/div/div[2]/input[2]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.switchTo().frame("resultsFrame");
            driver.findElement(By.linkText(sh.getRow(1).getCell(10).getStringCellValue())).click();
            driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:acctAdd:rptAddFields:7:actFields_lkwgt']/img")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Set<String> winhandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
            for(String str : winhandle)
            {   
                if(!str.equalsIgnoreCase(mainWindow))
                {
                    driver.switchTo().window(str);
                    break;
                }
            }
            try
            {
                driver.switchTo().frame("searchFrame");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lksrch']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(11).getStringCellValue());
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='theForm']/div/div[2]/input[2]")).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                driver.switchTo().frame("resultsFrame");
                driver.findElement(By.linkText(sh.getRow(1).getCell(11).getStringCellValue())).click();
                driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                System.out.println();
                driver.close();
                driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
                System.out.println("State/Region not Found");
            } 

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println();
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);           
        } 

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pg:acc:pb:j_id34:save']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, as vivek said in below, you first need to switch focus to window by using defaultContent method, then switch to resultFrame. For detailed explanation, watch this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYv_7-zYz4k"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before switching to `resultsFrame` try to switch to `defaultContent` or your main frame and then switch to `resultsFrame`. The thing is webdriver searches the frame in current context. So under searchFrame it will never find the resultsFrame (As both might be under main frame).

Hope this helps.